# How to group pairs in a list based on share items and connections in python

Tags: python, list, connection, group

Say I have a list, L1, of pairs such as:

```
L = [[9,3],[3,7],[7,5], [5,3], [9,5], [9,7], [2,5], [7,2], [2,8]]
```

I would like to cluster together values from pairs that are completely connected

for example [9,3] is connected to [3,7], [9,5], and [9,7].[3,7] is also connected to [7,5] which is connected to [9,5] making this an overlapping group of pairs.

likewise [7,5],[2,5], and [7,2] are also a group of overlapping pairs

however, [2,8] would not be a group.

Hence, as a final result, I would like to have a list such as

```
G = [[3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 5, 7], [2, 8]]
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this efficiently?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I found the most elegant way, but I think it solves your task.

```
L1 = [ [1,2], [2,6], [5,7], [1,6], [3,6], [2,3], [7,9], [6,7] ]
l1 = list(map(tuple, L1))
groups=set()
used = set()
#find groups:
for combi in itertools.combinations(l1,3):
    t1, t2, t3 = combi
    union = set(t1) | set(t2) | set(t3)
    if len(union) == 3:
        groups.add(tuple(union))
        used.update([t1,t2,t3])
print(groups)
# {(1, 2, 6), (2, 3, 6)}
print(used)
# {(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 6), (1, 6)}

#add tuples which are not in the groups:
result = list(groups) + [tup for tup in l1 if tup not in used]
print(result)

[(1, 2, 6), (2, 3, 6), (5, 7), (7, 9), (6, 7)]
```

If you are searching for bigger chain / unknown length chains then this one works aswell. As in the comments already discussed, if data gets big the performance is probably suboptimal.

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

#changed the input a bit for debugging reasons
L1 = [ [1,2], [2,5], [5,7], [7,8], [8,1], [5,4], [4,3], [3,7], [1,6], [5,6], [1,9] ]

l1 = list(map(tuple, L1))
len_chain_min = 3 # choose shortest valid chain
len_chain_max = 8 # choose highest valid chain
groups=set()
used = set()

#find groups:
for chains in range(len_chain_min, len_chain_max+1):
    for combi in itertools.combinations(l1,chains):
        combi_sets = list(map(set, [*combi]))
        union = set.union(*combi_sets)
        each_number_occurences = Counter((num for tupl in combi for num in tupl))
        # chain is only valid if every number never occurs more than twice, no brnaches aloud
        if (len(union) == chains) and (each_number_occurences.most_common(1)[0][1] <= 2):
            groups.add(tuple(union))
            used.update([*combi])
            print(f"number of tuples: {chains}\nunion group: {tuple(union)}\nused tuples for this group: {combi_sets}\n")

# add tuples which are not in the groups:
result = sorted(list(groups),key=len) + [tupl for tupl in l1 if tupl not in used]
print(f"{result=}")
```

Output:

```
number of tuples: 4
union group: (1, 2, 5, 6)
used tuples for this group: [{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {1, 6}, {5, 6}]

number of tuples: 4
union group: (3, 4, 5, 7)
used tuples for this group: [{5, 7}, {4, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}]

number of tuples: 5
union group: (1, 2, 5, 7, 8)
used tuples for this group: [{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {5, 7}, {8, 7}, {8, 1}]

number of tuples: 5
union group: (1, 5, 6, 7, 8)
used tuples for this group: [{5, 7}, {8, 7}, {8, 1}, {1, 6}, {5, 6}]

number of tuples: 7
union group: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8)
used tuples for this group: [{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {8, 7}, {8, 1}, {4, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}]

number of tuples: 7
union group: (1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
used tuples for this group: [{8, 7}, {8, 1}, {4, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {1, 6}, {5, 6}]

result=[(1, 2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 5, 7), (1, 5, 6, 7, 8), (1, 2, 5, 7, 8), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (1, 9)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this indeed works! However, I am wondering if it is also possible when there are more than 3 numbers as a group?

Comment: hm, my logic is based on 3 tuples which build a circle ONLY when their union of numbers is 3. if the circle contains 4 tuples, the union must be length of 4. But I don't know how to apply this if you don't know the length of the circle

Comment: changed my current answer a bite,because I found a little bug. Now it works for your first question (3 tuples build one group)

Comment: @Rabinzel - spot on. Clever use of *union*. But if the list is large, the *combinations* may be too *expensive*?  Upvote it.

Comment: @DanielHao thanks! yes, it is a bit of a try and error loop but for now I can't think of a better way to find these chains. Especially if (see comments) the chains also can have different lengths, then we would need an outer loop which also varies the 2nd input argument in `combinations`...this is getting really messy.

Comment: @Judith updated my answer for chains of different length. does that work for you?

Comment: @Rabinzel, thank you for your great and clever input. It is almost what I am looking for but not quite. for example union group: (1, 2, 5, 6)
used tuples for this group: [{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {1, 6}, {5, 6}],  but 2 and 6 are not directly connected neither are 5 and 1. I am looking for all values to be directly connected which each other as a connection between 5 & 6 and 1 &6 does not imply a connection between 1 & 6.

Comment: now I'm confused. If the chain are 3 tuples, I totally get your point, but if we are talking about chains and it gets bigger than 3, then we search for a "path" where at the end each number has like a "neighbour". That's at least how I understood. The example you just showed was for me: 1,2->2,5->5,6->6,1 ->chain closed. Could you give me an example how the tuples must look like for this example (1,2,5,6)?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, it works more like spatial overlap, so say 1 and 2 spatially overlap and so do 2 and 5, if 5 and 1 would also (spatially) overlap it would be kind of like a venn diagram (if that makes sense) and 2,5 and 1 would belong together. however here that is not the case so they would just be separate tuples. perhaps I should restructure my problem more spatially.

Comment: as I said, for 3 tuples that makes totally sense. I just don't quite get how the tuples should look like if there are more than 3 numbers as a group (as you asked in the first comment to this answer). Maybe just update your question with another example and desired output to it to make it more clear. I'd put some work into this, now I really want to solve it to everyone's satisfaction :D

Comment: I like the motivation haha, I updated the question and posted my answer to it below. I am sure there must be a better way to do it though. if you have any suggestions :)

Comment: @Judith not even sure if I understand what you are doing there :D maybe I'll better accept that it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
L = np.array([[9,3],[3,7],[7,5], [5,3], [9,5], [9,7], [2,5], [7,2], [2,8]]) #change list to array
G = []
for j in range(0, len(L)):
    
    f = np.where(L == L[j][0])[0]
    o = np.where(L == L[j][0])[1]
    o1 = o[f != j]
    f = f[f != j]
    used = []
    for g in range(0, len(f)):
        o2 = 1 - o1[g]
        if [L[f[g]][o2],L[j][1]] in L.tolist() or [L[j][1], L[f[g]][o2]] in L.tolist():
            coll = sorted([L[f[g]][o2],L[j][1], L[j][0]])
            if len(f) > 1:
                coll2 = coll.copy()
                coll2.remove(L[j][0])
                v = 0
                while v < len(f):
                    coll2 = coll.copy()
                    coll2.remove(L[j][0])
                    added = []
                    for b in coll2:
                        added.append([L[f[v]][ 1 - o1[v]],b] in L.tolist() or [b, L[f[v]][ 1 - o1[v]]] in L.tolist())
                    if all(added):   
                        coll.append(L[f[v]][ 1 - o1[v]])
                        coll = sorted(coll)
                        v +=1
                    else:
                        v +=1
                if coll in G:
                    used.append(0)
                else:
                    #print(j, g)
                    G.append(coll)
                    used.append(0)                          
            elif coll in G:
                used.append(0)
            else:
                G.append(coll)
                used.append(0)
        else:
          pass
    if 0 in used:
        pass
    else:
        G.append(list(L[j]))

print(G)
```

not the most efficient way but it works